# Binding a command to a child window's datacontext

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, command

I have a window called MAINWINDOW that has a toolbar and a frame. Inside the frame is shown a Page called HOMEPAGE. This page has a treeview where menu options are shown. When the user clicks a node, the corresponding form (a Page) is shown inside a border in HOMEPAGE, using the Border.Content property. I have a button in the toolbar to search for customers and I need to bind this button's command property to a command which is defined inside the Customers page's viewmodel. This page is a child of the HOMEPAGE which in turn is a child of MAINWINDOW. Can you suggest a way to do this, that is to access a command defined in a child's child object?
Thank you.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could show complex relations without writing a overly redundant wall of text with all-caps names. For example you could use an indented list for hierarchies and arrows for relationships. Alternatively or in addition you could give some sample code which illustrates your problem.

Comment: He's quite clear with his question..

Answer (score 0):

That goes against the principles of MVVM.

ViewModels (and their corresponding Commands) are 1:1 to Views. Each ViewModel serves one View, and one View ONLY. It helps to think of the ViewModel as the codeBehind of the View, only that it can never access the View directly (thus it's completely decoupled from it).

Violating this principle (V to VM == 1:1), creates dependencies between ViewModels or between Views, which is a bad thing. It makes your application harder to maintain since each "module" is dependent on the implementation of other "modules".

What you should do is expose another Command on the ViewModel that serves the relevant View. That Command in turn could trigger what ever you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time to answer. Even though your answer was very clear I still can't figure out how to make that SearchCustomer command bound to a toolbutton put the results into a collection bound to a grid in a page. I found that even though it is just one form, the datacontext cannot be accessed through a Frame: a frame acts as a boundary. Imagine this application as an MDI parent form with a toolbar with commands that act on objects inside MDI child forms

Comment: Try googling up ViewModelLocator. It's a pattern that allows (among other things) to access whatever ViewModel from any location.